# How to convert a user input string into an equations which can be used to find the best fit to some data

Tags: python, string, scipy, curve-fitting

I have some x and y data which I plot in a graph window. I would like a user to define an equation and then use something like SciPy to find the best values for that equation.

As an example equation
user input => y = ((m^2 / c^4) * 2)^0.5

How can I put this string into curve_fitting or something similar and find the missing values please? I thought I could use an anonymous function but that seems to not be working for me.

Comment: How do you tell what is the independent variable and what is the parameter to fit in the above equation?

Comment: I can ask the user to specify the equation in a different format. e.g. "[m],[y = ((m^2 / c^4) * 2)^0.5]". In this way the user has specified the independent variables for me

Comment: I have a Python open source example online at http://zunzun.com/Equation/2/UserDefinedFunction/UserDefinedFunction/ where you might use the source code as a guide for your own work. Links to the source code are at the bottom of the web page. It uses the Python AST parser to ensure only math function are used, so malicious Python code entered from the internet will not run.

Comment: Thanks James. I tried to run the example pyQt5Fit.py but I looked and cant find the file at all. Any ideas?

Comment: pyQt5Fit is a separate open source project with the git repository located at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/pyqt5fit

Comment: Thanks James. Ive got it now and will look to see if i can use it for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You might find lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful for this purpose. As part of its high-level approach to curve-fitting, it has an `ExpressionModel` class that supports user-defined model functions taken from Python expressions. More details can be found at
http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#user-defined-models. As a simple example (taken from the example folder in the github repo):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import ExpressionModel

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)

amp, cen, wid =  3.4, 1.8, 0.5

y = amp * np.exp(-(x-cen)**2 / (2*wid**2)) / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*wid)  
y = y + np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.01)

gmod = ExpressionModel('amp * exp(-(x-cen)**2 /(2*wid**2))/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid)')

result = gmod.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=5, wid=1)

print(result.fit_report())
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

will print out the results of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(_eval)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 54
    # data points      = 201
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.019
    reduced chi-square = 0.000
    Akaike info crit   = -1856.580
    Bayesian info crit = -1846.670
[[Variables]]
    amp:   3.40478705 +/- 0.005053 (0.15%) (init= 5)
    cen:   1.79930413 +/- 0.000858 (0.05%) (init= 5)
    wid:   0.50051059 +/- 0.000858 (0.17%) (init= 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(amp, wid)                  =  0.577
```

and produce a plot of
[image]

Just to be clear: this uses the asteval module (https://newville.github.io/asteval/) to parse and evaluate the user input in a way that tries to be as safe as possible from malicious user input that would be exposed using a plain `eval`.

Comment: What method did you use to determine the initial parameter values that you passed to the fit() routine in your example?

Comment: Hi James, in this example, the initial values are explicitly set by the user, as with `result = gmod.fit(y, x=x, amp=5, cen=5, wid=1)`.  We're not aiming for magically fitting every data set, just trying to help the user fit their data.  Then again, many builtin Models (such as GaussianModel and LorentzianModel) do have `guess` methods that heuristically try to get reasonable starting values for peak-like data.

Comment: My question is not whether the example code sets them explicitly. My question is, what method did you use to determine the values used in the example?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I just sort of guessed round numbers that were not too close, but not ridiculously wrong.  I think that for a simple Gaussian with a small amount of noise, it's pretty hard to go wrong.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at this also and see if i can use it