# Using a text input in tkinter as a function for further computations

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm building a small application with a GUI using *tkinter*. At one point a user would have to input a simple polynomial function (e.g. 2x^2 -3) into an entry widget. Is there a way to 'convert' the text input into a working python function?

I thought this could be possible by first defining the *x* variable as a symbol using *sympy*. But this does not work. Further I found an old [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950923/how-to-convert-a-user-input-string-into-an-equations-which-can-be-used-to-find-t) where someone else had a similar problem. Sadly the link to the probabyl most useful answer is dead.

Comment: You can use the [Sympy parser](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html)

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much exactly what I was looking for

Comment: What about the ```exec()``` function in Python?

Comment: It could be used as strings can be EASILY concatenated